# IllegalStateException: java.lang.NumberFormatException - ATU ReportListener

Tags: java, selenium, numberformatexception

I get this error when I try to run the testcases.but the same code works fine in the other machines.Why this error happened.How to solve this.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener.onStart(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.invokeListeners(SuiteRunner.java:197)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:238)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at com.ibm.pmc.selenium.main.GuiTestMain.main(GuiTestMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at atu.testng.reports.utils.SettingsFile.correctErrors(Unknown Source)
... 9 more
```

Comment: It seems that your test doesn't find the AtuReporter class.

Comment: A NumberFormatException is an unchecked exception and it can occur when you are trying to convert a String to a numeric value, like an Integer or a Float, but the String is not well formatted for the conversion. In your case, the String is null.

Comment: @peetya It is a NumberFormatException, not ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: Is AtuReporter class is a part of ATUReporter jar?

Comment: Can you post the correctErrors method in the SettingsFile class please?

Comment: @JamesB but when I tried after commenting the listeners of atu reporter it worked well.Where this exception is happening?

Comment: @james that class is in ATU Reporter jar

Answer (score 0):

I've even got the same error and fixed in this way ... try and you must get rid of the exception

1. Put the atu.properties file in your workspace and change the path where you've pointed to the properties

   {

   ```
   System.setProperty("atu.reporter.config",
                      "E:\\Fresh Start\\Practise Concepts Advanced\\atu.properties");
   ```

   }
2. You need to create a folder manually, where you want to store the result and then set the same thing in the `.properties` file.

ex: `u.reports.dir=E:/Fresh Start/Practise Concepts Advanced/ATU Reporter`

Does it make sense? Please reply if you need additional info.